# Select UIImage correctly

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have problem with show image chosed in switch. Im a beginner and don't know what is going wrong..

```
switch ImgSelect {
    case 0:
        inputImage1
        var inputedImage = inputImage1
    case 1:
        inputImage2
        var inputedImage = inputImage2
    case 2:
        inputImage3
        var inputedImage = inputImage3
    case 3:
        inputImage4
        var inputedImage = inputImage4
     default:
        inputImage1
    }
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named:inputedImage)
    MainImg.image = selectedImage      
}
```

@Code Different your option didn't work and i try to modify it. [whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ayIS.png),but I get fatal error.

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: What are your inputImage1, inputImage2, ... Are you sure they exist?

Comment: Is inputedImage in scope when you call UIImage?

Comment: @penarheboss i dont paste whole code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too verbose. Try this:

```
let images = ["inputImage1", "inputImage2", "inputImage3", "inputImage4"]
MainImg.image = ImgSelect < 4 ? UIImage(named: images[ImgSelect]) : UIImage(named: images[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem from beginning to end at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEA_EO0DL98&feature=youtu.be).